# Анимация в unity 3d

Tags: unity3d, анимация

У меня сть 1 префаб и на сцене создаю их 17 шт. Координаты каждого префаба разные. Но как мне сделать одну анимацию так, что бы при нажатии на объект он перемещался в заданную точку. Точка одна для всех префабов.

Comment: Не совсем понятно на какой объект вы нажимаете и что вы понимаете под словом анимация - простое перемещение к точке? ..... Сложите префабы в список или массив, а далее в `update` просто будете проходить в цикле по этому списку/массиву изменяя его координаты

Comment: @АлексейШиманский. да, простое перемещение. Но если через цикл, то для каждого нужно  задавать свое перемещение?!!

Comment: ну да.... у вас будет что-то типа `foreach (var obj : myObjects) {
 obj.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(obj.transform.position, target.position, step * Time.deltaTime);
}`  то есть у каждого объекта будет изменяться позиция по условию

Comment: @АлексейШиманский. Спасибо! Только я писал скипт для префаба и не нужно было массив создавать...

Comment: Ну ок. допустим есть метод `Move()` у скрипта, повешанного на прифаб. Все равно придется, скорее всего, в скрипте инициализаторе (который дает понять, что объектам надо начать двигаться) держать массив с ссылками на объекты. Чтоб в нужный момент времени просто пробежаться по массиву и сказать `obj.Move()`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне же нужно перемещать объект только при нажатии на объект, а не все сразу. И еще, как закрыть вопрос??))

Comment: ммм. я просто из этого `Точка одна для всех префабо` сделал вывод, что вам надо сразу всех перемещать в одну точку. ...значит просто `transform.translate`...... вопрос закрыть - правильный ответ написать и галочку на нем поставить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

```
float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
```